# CSS animation causes filter transition to break (in chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have several `<a>` in my html which are styled to have various images for their backgrounds. The desired behavior is for these `<a>` to be animated and scrolling across the page, as well as to have a grayscale filter applied. Then, when they are hovered they revert to normal, non-grayscale mode.

Unfortunately, in the latest version of chrome the animation css rule seems to interfere with the transition. I have reproduced the error in the code snippet below. Notice that upon first hovering over either of the animated `<div>`s, they will not transition to reveal their color, but rather jump to the end animation state (namely, `filter: none`) instantly. And no, making the hovered css say `filter: grayscale(0)` instead of `filter: none` does not fix it.

If immediately after this you move your mouse in an out of the `<div>`s bounds repeatedly, you will notice the transition appearing to work normally. However if you move your mouse away for too long or try the other `<div>`, the transition breaks again.

I have not found this to be an issue in Firefox or Brave, but what's more I seem to remember that when I implemented this feature in my site I tested it in chrome and *it worked*, so it must have been broken in the meantime. I'm really stumped on how I might be able to fix this, or in the case that it is a bug in chrome at least work around it temporarily.

```css
.thing {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: filter 1s;
}

.thing:hover {
  filter: none;
}

.broken {
  animation: move linear 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(500%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="broken thing">TEST1</div>
<div class="broken thing">TEST2</div>
<br>
<div class="thing">noanim</div>
<div class="thing">noanim</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, I can't repro on neither Chrome 103.0.5060.53 stable nor on today's Canary 105 in macOS. To report issues on Chromium: https://crbug.com

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome Version 102.0.5005.115, Windows 11. After an update to the latest build the bug is gone. A simple hack I got working is to just add `border: solid 0` to the hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was a bug in chrome. The version in which I was encountering the error was Version **102.0.5005.115**, 64-bit.

As misterManSam pointed out, updating seems to solve the issue. After relaunching chrome to finish the update (now using Version **103.0.5060.66**) the transition behaves as expected.

I assumed I had the latest version since chrome was not asking me to update, but annoyingly only by going to [chrome://settings/help](https://chrome://settings/help) was I able to see that I had to restart chrome to finish updating. For anyone facing this issue, make sure your browser is fully updated by relaunching.